# Ubuntu not installed-Please Remove installation media and close tray and press enter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have downloaded **Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS 32 bit**, burned it on DVD and tried to install it on my PC.
My PC is running in Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit mounted on the C: drive. Now I want install Ubuntu along with my Windows 7.

When I boot Ubuntu through the CD,

1. It boots and the Ubuntu install windows opens
2. It offers "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu". I choose "Install Ubuntu"
3. Then I go on to install Ubuntu with Windows(First Option)->install
4. It shows some blank screen with some lines, and says **"Please Remove installation media and close tray and press enter"**
5. Then the PC restarts and runs Windows 7 same as before normally. But Ubuntu is not installed. How to solve this problem and install Ubuntu on my PC properly?

Note: I am an Android Developer. So I need to install Ubuntu for my Android Development purpose.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. Also, you do not need Ubuntu for developing Android SDK applications, if you would prefer to stick with Windows.

Comment: Maybe he is working on Android *itself*?

Comment: You're a developer? Rule #1: Take note of the error messages. If you need assistance, post the error messages.

Comment: You can also try wubi method to install ubuntu, just insert your DVD while windows is running and install it like any other application.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that it is not due to the live DVD or its content. Burn another DVD and/or download Ubuntu 12.04 again. If it still does not work, try the alternate CD.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not see a boot loader before Windows boots? From the bootloader (guessing it's GRUB), choose Ubuntu

"Please Remove installation media and close tray and press enter" *should* mean a successful installation.

Comment: This message is displayed at the end of the shutdown/reboot script and has nothing to do with whether or not the installation completed successfully.  For example, it appears after ending a Ubuntu live session even if there it is not installed to the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it's not the cd...I tried with several versions, usb, etc. In my case it was that I was trying to install ubuntu in a partition I made in Windows...somehow I didn't do it right. I remove that partition and install it without trouble. I recommend to do that, remove partitions and allow ubuntu do it's own partition in the moment of installation.
Adriana.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. my mistake during installation was having 4 primary partitions. in this situation ubuntu can't use the free space of your memory. you can delete one of your primary partitions after getting backup from it and make an extended partition instead of that. be careful to not to delete the drive which your OS has been installed on it (usually drive with letter C). after these operations you can install ubuntu alongside your windows. it's good to have about 40GB free space for ubuntu to install any application you want.